# What is the difference between “violet” and “pourpre” in French?

Tags: sens, traduction

Violet and Purple are treated as distinct colours in the English language. However, I have learned that in French “violet” is the umbrella term for both purple and violet. Is this true? Also, what is the colour “pourpre” then?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/regional-usage-of-violet-and-purple English often call *purple* what French call *violet*. French would say the actual color of a *choix rouge* is *violet* (and would never say *pourpre*) while English would generally say the color of a red cabbage is purple...

Comment: Note that neither French nor English would say a red cabbage / *choux rouge* is red / *rouge* ;-)

Answer (score 7):

In more technical areas of color discussion, what is "purple" in English (i.e. everything between indigo and magenta on the color wheel) is divided between "pourpre" on the reddish side of things (*Pourpre* being originally what English refers to specifically as *Tyrian* purple) and "violet" on the bluish side of things. (cf. Trésor de la langue française s.v.  [Pourpre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourpre) & [Violet](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/violet), French Wikipedia...)

In the common language, however, *pourpre* has in practice evolved toward just being a general elevated/poetic synonym of *violet* (which now is roughly synonymous with English purple), because the specific shades of color that *pourpre* originally referred to are nowadays more likely to be referred to with wine-related words such as *bordeaux* or *lie-de-vin*.

Comment: Héritage/appropriation catholique de *pourpre* : 
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pourpre+pontificale&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpourpre%20pontificale%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpourpre%20pontificale%3B%2Cc0 d’origine romaine https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pourpre **B.2.b**

Comment: As an aside for completeness, in Belgium *mauve* has displaced *violet* as the generic term for purple, relegating in the process *violet* back to the bluer subset of this part of the spectrum.

Comment: Color terms have always been a little messy, and doubly so now that color terms are significantly affected by fashionmaking, especially from paint company (I read in an article years ago that they specifically avoided the word "mauve" in any color name at the time because it's used for less saturated versions of purple/violet in North America, and that wasn't fashionable back then.)

Comment: @Circeus — Même si c’est un peu passé de mode, c’est la couleur préférée de certains corbillards pompes-funebres-dieppoises-privees-sarl.business.site/?m=true … violet, mauve, parme étaient des nuances de la couleur préférée des grand-mères bourgeoises d’après-guerres (première et seconde).